# iCloud: App verifies in Xamarin Studio but not in XCode

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Xamarin iOS app which uses the iCloud. I configured my Provisioning Profiles and my app ID properly and refreshed them on my development machine. When I attempt to validate an application package in Xcode Organzier (while uploading) there are four errors:

- Invalid Code Signing Entitlements: Used Entitlements (`com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers` in `Payload/vplan.app/vplan`) that are not supported in iOS
- Invalid Code Signing Entitlements: Used Entitlements (`com.apple.developer.icloud-container-development-container-identifiers` in `Payload/vplan.app/vplan`) that are not supported in iOS
- Invalid Code Signing Entitlements: Used Entitlements (`com.apple.developer.icloud-services` in `Payload/vplan.app/vplan`) that are not supported in iOS
- Invalid Code Signing Entitlements: Used Entitlements (`com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment` in `Payload/vplan.app/vplan`) that are not supported in iOS

Not only that I never set these keys, these errors also don't show up when validating in Xamarin Studio.

Here's the `Entitlements.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.centrallink.vplan</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This problem drives me crazy so I would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Same problem here. I use Xcode6 beta to develop for an existing Objective C app.

Comment: I have Xcode beta 6-2 installed but I use the Xcode 5 Organizer for validation.

Comment: I also use Xcode 5 for validation but maybe the errors happen because of the "new iCloud api" or something like this...

Comment: Do you target iOS 8 or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you file a bug report about this on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com under `Xamarin Studio` / `iOS Addin`?

It looks like what is happening is that new Provisioning Profiles are starting to include new keys in the Entitlements section that Xamarin Studio needs to add to avoid merging into the `.xcent` file.

As a temporary workaround, you could probably edit that file and remove those keys manually and then re-sign.

If you look at the Build Log, you should be able to see what the command lines are to codesign your app bundle.

I'll try to patch this up on Monday and see if I can make sure it gets into the next hotfix release.

Comment: I will accept the answer as soon as I get the hack to work or when a Hotfix is available.